# Is it mean to call someone "a joker"?

Tags: word-usage, meaning-in-context

My boy in 2nd grade told me that some girls called him a joker at school. I am not a native English speaker; I do not know what it means. Is it something bad or good?

Comment: It would depend on the context (really).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not as easy as just considering which word was used - usually you need to know more context. However the word "joker" is not a generally a curse word or taboo, so that's a good start.
The most direct meaning is just "a person who makes jokes". In this case it starts neutral, but of course it depends on what kind of jokes and what the speaker intends. It could be a positive thing if the girls enjoyed his jokes.
"Joker" may also be a reference to a popular character from comic books and the Batman movies, the Joker.

Comment: thanks. I also think that joker should not be a bad word.